# Pandas DataFrame String Quotation Display Option

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas DataFrame omits the quotation marks when it displays strings.

```
In [43]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['foo', 'bar', 'bim', 'uncomfortably'],
   ....:                             ['horse', 'cow', 'banana', 'apple']]))
   ....: 


In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
       0    1       2              3
0    foo  bar     bim  uncomfortably
1  horse  cow  banana          apple
```

How do I make it display strings within quotation marks like below?

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
         0      1        2                3
0    'foo'  'bar'     'bim'  'uncomfortably'
1  'horse'  'cow'  'banana'          'apple'
```

I know if I do

```
 df[0][0]
```

It returns

```
'foo' (with quotation marks)
```

however I'd like to see the quotation marks even when I call the dataframe as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert all values to their string representations:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda row: [repr(x) for x in row])
         0      1         2                3
0    'foo'  'bar'     'bim'  'uncomfortably'
1  'horse'  'cow'  'banana'          'apple'
```

This is equivalent to :

```
df.applymap(repr)
```

as suggested by DSM in a comment.

`df.apply()` works row-by-row, where `df.applymap()` works element-wise.

Comment: (Or `df.applymap(repr)`.)

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the hint. Updated my answer.